# Awk solution to take column based information from txt

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Using bash shell, I am analysing a huge number of txt files located within the same directory.

Each of the txt files share the same format:

```
largestCl_dlgfn #runs #cl #LC #LE_LC #rmsd_LC #ats #tors #h_ats #lig_eff 
 /Users/fox/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig1000/7000_08_lig_cne_1000,240,206,  5, -5.3000, 238.4025,  22, 4, 1,  0.0000
```

or

```
largestCl_dlgfn #runs #cl #LC #LE_LC #rmsd_LC #ats #tors #h_ats #lig_eff
 /Users/fox/Desktop/DOcking/clusterizator/sub_folders_to_analyse/7000_CNE_lig1001/7000_04_lig_cne_1001,240, 56, 26, -5.2900, 206.1682,  13, 1, 1,  0.0000
```

I need to write simple shell script suitable to loop all the log files, to take the name of the file as well as to extract (e.g. using Awk) the numbers from 4th and 6th columns of the second line of the log. All three entities should be separated using `|` in the `final_output.txt` (which should be updated each time in loop while adding new line corresponding to each processed text).

The expected output from the above log should be one line

```
name_of_the_log.log| -5.6800| 15
```

And for N logs the `final_output` obviously should contain N lines always in the same format.

Dealing with the analysis of many logs the bash workflow could be in the following format:

```
#!/bin/bash
logs=$PWD/tmp/*.txt
for f in $logs; do
  # take the name of the file and subtract its extension
  file_name=$(basename "$f")
  file_name="${file_name/.txt}"
  echo "Processing of $f..."
  #example of Awk solution which does not always match correctly the proper column
  awk '-F, *' '{if(NR==2) printf("%s| %s| %s\n", FILENAME,$5,$7) }' ${f} >> final_log.txt
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can process all the files at once:

```
awk '-F, ' '{if(FNR==2) printf("%s| %s| %s\n", FILENAME,$4,$6) }' *.txt
```

Alternative for mixed `,` and `,`  separated columns:

```
awk '-F, *' '{if(FNR==2) printf("%s| %s| %s\n", FILENAME,$5,$7) }' *.txt
```

To get rid of the path to the files:

```
awk '-F, *' '{if(FNR==2){sub(".*/","",FILENAME);printf("%s| %s| %s\n",FILENAME,$5,$7)}}' *.txt
```

... or by changing directory first:

```
#!/bin/bash

process() {
    OD=$PWD
    cd tmp
    awk '-F, *' '{if(FNR==2) printf("%s| %s| %s\n", FILENAME,$5,$7) }' *.txt
    cd "$OD"
}

process > result.txt
```